# Ngrx meta-reducer in featureModule handle action of all featureModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I'm using @ngrx since some time now and came accross an issue with meta-reducers.

I implemented a meta-reducer for one of my featureModule inside which I just do a `console.log` of the action/state.

When launching the application I saw that actions of the others featureModule (ex: routerStore => type: "@ngrx/router-store/navigation") where also appearing inside my meta-reducer, I was expecting to only see action of my specific featureModule.

Is this the intended behavior ?

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An action is send to all meta-reducers, reducers, and effects.
This is the intended behavior.

It's perfectly fine to handle an action inside multiple reducers (even when they're registered in multiple features)

Comment: Ok thank you for the answer, I thought that all that happened inside a specific featureModule was isolated from the others featureModule.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's intended behavior because router store is config for whole of your application. The router store module have seperate store for router navigation event inside your app.